Gunicorn on Apache Server not serving static files in Django project: "Not Found" error for /static/
I’m running a Django project using Gunicorn and Apache with mod_wsgi, but Gunicorn is not serving the static files correctly. When I try to load my page, I get errors like:
Not Found: /static/css/style.css
Not Found: /static/js/app.js
In browser console I get
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost/static/css/style.css' because its MIME type 
('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is 
enabled.

Additionally, when I try to access the static files directly (e.g., http://localhost:9090/static/css/style.css), I get a 404 error. The static files are correctly configured in the Django settings, but Gunicorn is not able to locate them.
Environment:
Django version: 5.1
Gunicorn version: 20.x.x
Apache version: 2.4.x
mod_wsgi version: 4.9.0
Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04
Python version: 3.10
Running inside a virtual environment
Django Static Configuration (settings.py):
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'app/static')]

INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'userentry', //my django app
]

Current Setup:
Apache is proxying requests to Gunicorn.
Static files are collected in the STATIC_ROOT directory using python manage.py collectstatic.
I have confirmed that the static files are located at /app/static/ on the server.
My apache virtualhost:
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName localhost

ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:9090/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:9090/

# Point WSGI to the proper directories
WSGIDaemonProcess malwarepurge python-home=/app/venv python-path=/app/malwarepurge
WSGIProcessGroup malwarepurge
WSGIScriptAlias /app /app/malwarepurge/wsgi.py

Alias /static/ /app/static/

# Allow access to the necessary app files (including other directories in /app)
<Directory /app>
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

# Specifically grant access to the malwarepurge folder for WSGI
<Directory /app/malwarepurge>
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /app/static>
Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /app/userentry/>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Steps Taken:
I have added STATIC_URL, STATICFILES_DIRS, and STATIC_ROOT in the Django settings.
I’ve run python manage.py collectstatic to gather the static files in the specified directory.
I’ve configured Apache to use mod_wsgi for serving the Django app.
Gunicorn is running but is unable to serve static files directly.
Apache should be serving the static files, but Gunicorn still reports a "Not Found" error when trying to access them.
What I’ve Tried:
Double-checked the STATIC_URL, STATIC_ROOT, and STATICFILES_DIRS settings.
Ensured the static files are correctly located in /app/static/.
Tried restarting both Apache and Gunicorn after making configuration changes.
Verified that the paths to static files are correct and that Gunicorn is running on the correct IP/port.
Checked that mod_wsgi is properly installed and enabled.

Gunicorn is not designed to serve static files. Static files should be served by Apache directly, bypassing Gunicorn.

Read thoroughly through the post please

as Asif noted, Gunicorn does not serve static files. that is offloaded to your webserver (Nginx or Apache). this is evident in your apache config Alias /static/ /app/static/

Here is what my apache config looks like. I don't have the second / after static and i use static_root. not static.. esp in prod.
Alias /static /path-to-app/static_root
